# Cannot run program "/system/bin/ping" in Unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing

I have written a method to get the ping which looks like:

```kotlin
    fun ping(host: String): String {
        return try {
            val ip = Inet4Address.getByName(host)
            val ping = ip.hostAddress?.let { executePing(it) }
            Log.d(TAG, "Executed: $ping")
            ping.toString()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            ""
        }
    }

    private fun executePing(host: String): List<String> {
        return try {
            val output = mutableListOf<String>()
            val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -w 1 -c 1 $host")
            Log.d(TAG, "Exec: $process")

            val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
            input.readLines().forEach { output.add(it) }
            output
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            mutableListOf()
        }
    }
```

These methods work on `127.0.0.1` perfectly fine.
Now I want to write some Unit tests for them. Im pretty new in testing, so my understanding is very rudimentary. I researched a bit and made this to get to know how it works:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MCxCoreUtilitiesUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun `ping on localhost`() = runTest{
        val ping = "127.0.0.1"
        val core = MCxCoreUtilities
        val expectedOutputRegex = Regex(".*64 bytes from.*")
        val result = core.ping(ping)
        assertEquals(result, expectedOutputRegex)
    }
}
```

This test fails with this error:

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/system/bin/ping": error=2, No such file or directory`
My guess is that i have to do something to get access to the ping program, but I cant find anything related to this. Do tests have some restricted access?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly does that the ping program exist in the location on the machine you are running this code?  Just try that in a shell.  The error you are getting is saying that the program cannot be found. There is nothing different about Unit Tests.

There are several things that will trip you up afterwards.

1. Whilst it is normal in a shell to write `/system/bin/ping -w 1 -c 1 XXX`, what the shell is doing for you is executing `/system/bin/ping` and passing it a series of arguments `-w` `1` `-c` `1` `XXX`.  You need to alter the call to exec() to take an array.  See here: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D))
2. Making calls to the Operating System is fraught with all sorts of difficulties (not least portability to another machine / operating system).  You might want to take a look at this high level function:
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html
3. Your assertion (`assertEquals(result, expectedOutputRegex)`) is going to fail.   The `result` is a `String` and it certainly is not going be EQUAL to a Regular Expression.  You want something more like:

```
assertEquals(expectedOutputRegex.matches(result), true)
```